# what are the differences between alignment and colinear?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization

Im reading a chapter talking about orthogonal complement of dual space in optimization by vector space. And the author introduced a definition of Alignment as following: 
[image]

where X* means the dual of X and < x , x* > denote a functional as following:
[image]

What are the differences between the alignment and colinear? Can you give me more examples? Thank you^_^

P. S.

1. Riesz-Frechet:

[image]

2. Riesz Representation Theorem:
   [image]

Comment: Luenberger? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat Yes!

Comment: @copper.hat:Thanks for ur reply. Your answer does make a lot of sense. However, Im still confusing by some ideas:1. I've noted that u said the dual of hilbert space and itself are isomorphic and actually, the dual of hilbert space is itself, is that right? 2. I've checked the Riesz representation theorem and seen it in talking about C[a,b] which will have been attached above. Actually, I've seen Riesz-Frechet in something about the dual of hilbert space, what are the differences between them? 3. ur last good example say s = (1,1,1,....) which means that s will not belong to the space X,right?

Comment: @copper.hat: I've reedit the question by adding a P.S. and I really appreciate ur kindness and patience^_^

Comment: Well, think of isomorphic as being essentially the same, in the way that one thinks of $l_\infty$ as the dual of $l_1$. That is, there is a distinction between a continuous linear functional on $l_1$ and an element of $l_\infty$ (one is a function, one is a point), but we can identify them in a meaningful way.

Comment: I added a simple example in $C[0,1]$. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Frank_W : I upvoted your question because you spelled "colinear" with a single l.  Two l's strikes me as nonsensical.  What's the point of an extra l?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual space is not an element of the underlying space, so, in general, it doesn't make sense to talk about collinear. Informally, however, alignment is basically the same idea, taking the different spaces into account.

For Hilbert spaces, the Riesz representation theorem shows that the space and its dual are isomorphic (antilinear, depending on your taste), so we can identify the dual and the underlying space as in the case of $\mathbb{C}^n$, for example.

For an example, take $X= l_1$, then $X^* = l_\infty$ (or, at least, identified with). Define $\sigma \in X^*$ by $\sigma(x) = \sum_n x_n$. Then $s$ is aligned with $x$ iff $s(x) = \|s\| \|x||$. Since $\|s\| = 1$, $s$ and $x$ are aligned **iff** $s(x) = \|x\|$, which is easily seen to be equivalent to $x_n = |x_n|$ for all $n$. Note that (as an element of $l_\infty$) we have $s=(1,1,...)$, so we cannot identify $s$ with any element of $X$.

Luenberger's book has an example involving the dual of $C[0,1]$ which illustrates the point a little more.

As an analog of the above, consider $f$ a continuous linear functional on $C[0,1]$ given by $f(x) = \int_0^1 x(t)dt$ (that is, the average value of $x$).
It is easy to see that $\|f\| = 1$, so to look for aligned points, we solve $f(x) = \|x\|$. Since $x$ is continuous, we see that $\int_0^1 x(t) dt = \max_t |x(t)|$ **iff** $x(t) = \max_t |x(t)|$ for all $t$, that is the constant functions whose value is non-negative.

Another example (well, not exactly) in $C[0,1]$ is $f(x) = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} x(t) dt- \int_\frac{1}{2}^1 x(t) dt$. A little work shows that $\|f\| = 1$ and $|f(x)| < \|x\|$ for all $x$, and so there are **no** non-zero vectors that are aligned with $f$.